# Apache - how do I build individual and/or all modules as shared modules

Tags: apache, unix, configuration, mod-rewrite, build

On Mac OS X 10.5 I downloaded the latest version of Apache 2.2.9. After the usual configure, make, make install dance I had a build of apache without mod_rewrite. This wasn't statically linked and the module was not built in the /modules folder either.

I had to do the following to build Apache and mod_rewrite:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-rewrite=shared
```

- Is there a way to tell Apache to build all modules as Shared Modules (DSOs) so I can control loading from the Apache config?
- Now that I have built Apache and the mod_rewrite DSO, how can I build another shared module without building all of Apache?

(The last time I built Apache (2.2.8) on Solaris, by default it built everything as a shared module.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the `./configure` option `--enable-mods-shared="all"`, or  `--enable-mods-shared="<list of modules>"` to compile modules as shared objects. See further [details in Apache 2.2 docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/configure.html#otheroptfeat)

To just compile Apache with the ability to load shared objects (and add modules later), use `--enable-so`, then consult the documentation on compiling modules seperately in the [Apache 2.2. DSO docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/dso.html).

Comment: "all" doesn't really mean all! You should use ./configure --with-ldap --enable-mods-shared="all ssl ldap cache proxy authn_alias mem_cache file_cache authnz_ldap charset_lite dav_lock disk_cache" instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared="all" --enable-proxy=shared
```

To get rewrite, proxy and bunch of other modules, I used the above command. In my previous installation, using --enable-mods-shared="all" compiled/installed the proxy module as well. But in `v2.2.22`  "all" did not include the proxy module.